# Powershell new User creation

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find out if there is a cmd that will create a new user in AD but able to pull in the AD services folder from another person that already exists i.e. managers groups or member of.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Get-ADUser and Set-ADUser cmdlets, provided by the MS ActiveDirectory module.
(If installed, you can add it to the powershell session with: import-module activedirectory)

Once you have it loaded, you can get the AD User you wish to 'copy', look for their "MemberOf" attribute and note them, then you can user Add-ADGroupMember for each of those groups.

Microsoft has good references here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx